# Error in installing rgl and shiny package

Tags: r, installation, install.packages

I am trying to do a scatter3d(y ~ x1+ x2), but I am getting the following error:

```
Loading required namespace: rgl
Failed with error:  ‘there is no package called ‘shiny’’
Error in scatter3d(Vent ~ O2 + CO2) : rgl package missing
```

I have tried to install rgl in the following way:

```
install.packages("rgl", repos = c("http://rstudio.org/_packages", "http://cran.rstudio.com"))
install.packages("rgl", depositories = TRUE)
```

Getting this error:

```
Errore: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgl’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘shiny’
```

And if I try to install shiny in the same way that I did for rgl, I get the following

```
ERROR: dependency 'htmltools' is not available for package 'shiny'
* removing 'C:/Users/franc/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/shiny'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'shiny' is not available for package 'shinytest'
* removing 'C:/Users/franc/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/shinytest'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘shinytest’ had non-zero exit status
```

Does anyone know what is going on and how I can solve this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you mean to use `dependencies = TRUE`?

Comment: Yes! I am sorry.. typing mistake!

Comment: You could restart your session, remove packages (either with `remove.packages(...)` or manually) and then attempt to install again